# Find files with spaces in findstr

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I have this batch code and it works ONLY when the files do not have space in the name.
What can I do to also find the files that include spaces in the name?

```
@echo off
echo.open localhost >file.tmp
echo.user user1 user1 >>file.tmp
echo.dir >>file.tmp
echo.bye >>file.tmp

FTP -n <file.tmp >output.tmp
Del file.tmp

echo.open localhost >file.tmp
echo.user user1 user1 >>file.tmp
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO call :Existe %%A
echo.bye >>file.tmp

FTP -n <file.tmp >nul
DEL file.tmp
DEL output.tmp
GOTO :EOF

:Existe
    Findstr /I %1 output.tmp > nul
    IF NOT %ErrorLevel% == 0 ECHO.put %1 >>file.tmp
```

I also do that, but it does not work

```
:Existe
    Findstr /I /c:"%1" output.tmp > nul
    IF NOT %ErrorLevel% == 0 ECHO.put "%1" >>file.tmp
```

Comment: `DO call :Existe "%%A"` and adjust instances of `"%1"` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the batch is in the current dir it will also transfer itself and
  file.tmp containing login data.
- findstr /G option can process the check for existence more
  efficiently against a dir of the current folder.
- To exclude the batch itself from transfer insert an additional `^|find /V "%0"`

---

```
@echo off
Set "Host=localhost" & If "%~1" neq "" Set "Host=%~1"
Set "User=user1"     & If "%~2" neq "" Set "User=%~2"
Set "Pass=user1"     & If "%~3" neq "" Set "Pass=%~3"

(echo.open %Host%
 echo.user %User% %Pass%
 echo.dir
 echo.bye
) >file.tmp

FTP -n <file.tmp >output.tmp
Del file.tmp

(echo.open %Host%
 echo.user %User% %Pass%
 FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO call :Existe "%%A"
 echo.bye
) >file.tmp

FTP -n <file.tmp >ftp.log
DEL file.tmp
DEL output.tmp

GOTO :EOF

:Existe
Echo:%~1|Findstr /I "\.tmp$ \.cmd$">NUL 2>&1 && Goto :Eof
Findstr /I "%~1" output.tmp >nul 2>&1 ||ECHO.put "%~1"
```

Comment: Excellent works very well with spaces, the problem is that they overwrite the files that are already inside the FTP, the / G: does not work.
They are in the same directory

Comment: I'm looking into it, I need to know how the dir output is looking, could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45422812/edit) your question to include a sample (if necessary neutralized)?

Comment: No entiendo lo que significa, soy nuevo en la programación en LOTE, Everything works fine, just looking for files that are already included in the output re-overwrites them

Comment: Danielle I'm sorry - my logic had a flaw, presumaly the remote dir contains additional information - so this won't match the local file names. I reverted the above batch to your approach with additional checks and quoting the file names to overcome the spaces issue. You can optionally pass the Host,User and Password via cmd line arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help, it has helped me a lot and I found a way to solve it. I changed the echo.dir by echo.! DIR / B / A-D with the address of the remote folder